# How to insert 1 million rows into Oracle database with Python?

Tags: python, database, oracle, insert, oracle18c

I have ~100,000 to 1,000,000 rows to insert into an Oracle18c database. I'm quite new with Oracle and this order of magnitude of data. I reckon there must be some optimal way to do it, but for now I've only managed to implement a line by line insertion:

```
def insertLines(connection, table_name, column_names, rows):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    if table_exists(connection, table_name):
        for row in rows:
            sql = 'INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(table_name, column_names, row)
            cursor.execute(sql)
    cursor.close()
```

Is there some clear way in Oracle to bulk the rows to reach higher effectivity using cx_Oracle (the python Oracle library)?

EDIT: I read the data from a CSV file.

Comment: what about pandas and dataframes?

Comment: this is what you want --> https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.executemany also never never never never use string interpolation when inserting data

Comment: @MAhsan 
Sadly I don't know pandas. I'm reading from a CSV file, should I focus on a pandas implementation?

Comment: No harm in trying it, it has an easy to use read_csv method. Then a to_sql method, this requires setting up the engine for which you could use cx_Oracle. Of course, if you have 100k+ rows, it will take a bit of time but could do it all in one go. Here is a handy link for creating the engine connection https://gist.github.com/DGrady/7fb5c2214f247dcff2cb5dd99e231483

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is already in Python, then use [`executemany()`](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.executemany).  In your case with so many rows, you probably would still execute multiple calls to insert batches of records.

Update: see the cx_Oracle documentation [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Update 2: the latest release of cx_Oracle (which got renamed to [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)) runs in a 'Thin' mode by default which bypasses the Oracle Client libraries.  This means that in many cases it is faster for data loads. The usage and functionality of `executemany()` is still the same in the new release.  Install with something like `python -m pip install oracledb`. Here's the current documentation for [Executing Batch Statement and Bulk Loading](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html). Also see the [upgrading documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_c.html#upgrading-from-cx-oracle-8-3-to-python-oracledb).

Here's an example using the python-oracledb namespace.  If you still use cx_Oracle then change the `import` to be `import cx_Oracle as oracledb`:

```
import oracledb
import csv

...
Connect and open a cursor here...
...

# Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition.
# This can improve performance by avoiding memory reallocations.
# Here, one parameter is passed for each of the columns.
# "None" is used for the ID column, since the size of NUMBER isn't
# variable.  The "25" matches the maximum expected data size for the
# NAME column
cursor.setinputsizes(None, 25)

# Adjust the number of rows to be inserted in each iteration
# to meet your memory and performance requirements
batch_size = 10000

with open('testsp.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    sql = "insert into test (id,name) values (:1, :2)"
    data = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        data.append((line[0], line[1]))
        if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
            data = []
    if data:
        cursor.executemany(sql, data)
    con.commit()
```

As pointed out by others:

- Avoid using string interpolation in statements because it is a security risk.
  It is also generally a scalability problem.  Use bind variables.  Where you need to use string interpolation for things like column names, make sure you santize any values.
- If the data is already on disk, then using something like SQL*Loader or Data Pump will be better than reading it into cx_Oracle and then sending it to the DB.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I'm reading from a CSV, and I have it on my disk. What's the difference between SQL*Loader and Data Pump?

Comment: sqlldr reads data from csv files and inserts it into a table.  Exactly what you want.  DataPump is a generic term for the 'expdp' and 'impdp' utilites.  expdp 'exports data and metadata (essentially a bunch of CREATE and INSERT commands) and writes it to a propriatary binary file.  impdp reads that binary file and executes the CREATE and INSERT commands to import the data and metadata into a database.  Both are fully documented at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/toc.htm

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what format you have the data in, but [SQL Data Loader](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/sql-loader-overview-095816.html) is a command line utility specifically created for adding large amounts of data to Oracle.

Comment: Then Data Loader would probably be the best way to load your data.

Comment: SQL Loader would be the 2nd best option

Answer (score 1):

The most optimal way in terms of performance and easy would be to create an External Table over your CSV file and then use SQL do the insert.