# concert python dataframe into a format that can be used in oracle bulk insert

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi we have a python dataframe that is created from an excel xls.

How we can convert that dataframe into a format like this ?

```
data = [
    (60, "Parent 60"),
    (70, "Parent 70"),
    (80, "Parent 80"),
    (90, "Parent 90"),
    (100, "Parent 100")
]
```

We like to do bulk insert into an oracle table and the excel file has 1.3 million rows

[How to insert 1 million rows into Oracle database with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271615/how-to-insert-1-million-rows-into-oracle-database-with-python)

Comment: can you show the original dataframe

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]

This works. However, it is easier just to scrub the data with python
and load it with sqlldr.